# Can I use 2 loop statement in one loop?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

is this loop statement is correct?
if not correct then what alternative way?
I am trying to o(n) loop statement like this-

```
for(int i=0 ; i<n  ; i++ , j=n ; j<n*2 ; j++){
    continue;
  }
```

Comment: This does not make sense...what is the terminating criteria?

Comment: No, the loop statement is not correct.

Comment: Should it terminate when both conditions are true or when only one is true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The construct is wrong, you cannot you two loops in one construct, but you can have more than one variable controlling the iteration.

For example, you can have

- Two (or more) variables, `i` and `j`, initialized with certain values.
- A loop controlling statement, involving operation and condition check on `i` and `j` (and others, if defined).
- Finally, you can control the increment or decrement of `i` and `j`  (and others, if defined).

A sample construct can be:

```
 for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n && j < n * 2; ++i, ++j)
                                            |^^^^^^^| -------- variable modification
      |               |   |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^| ---------------- loop condition
      |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|--------------------------------------- initialization
```

Answer (score 10):

What you seem to want is something like:

```
for (int i = 0, j = n; i < n && j < n * 2; ++i, ++j)
{
    continue;
}
```

---

To help you better understand what I did and why, and how you can do such transformations in the future, you need to understand how a `for` loop is really handled by the compiler: As a special `while` loop.

For example, if you have

```
for (a; b; c)
{
    d;
}
```

then that's equivalent to this:

```
{
    a;
    while (b)
    {
        d;
        c;
    }
}
```

If we take what you (probably) want, in the form of a `while` loop then it would be

```
{
    int i = 0, j = n;  // a in my example above
    while (i < n && j < n * 2)  // b in my example above
    {
        continue;  // d in my example above
        ++i, ++j;  // c in my example above
    }
}
```

Now it's easy to translate it to the `for` loop I showed initially.

As noted in a comment, the `while` loop shown here is a little misleading, as it won't actually do the increment. But then I assume your real loop doesn't have an unconditional `continue` statement as the only statement in the body. That would make the loop rather meaningless. However the *principle* is still valid, even if the example isn't.

Comment: I find this kind of misleading. In your "translation" `c` is never reached when `d` is a continue - while in reality `i` and `j` are increased each round. Maybe you could point this out a little more.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0 ; i<n  ; i++ , j=n ; j<n*2 ; j++){
    continue;
  }
```

The above code is wrong
but it can be written as

```
for(int i = 0 ,j = n; i < n ,j < n * 2; i++ ,j++)
```

The above code is correct
`i=0` and `j=n` is  initialization
`i<n` and `j<n*2` is loop condition
`i++` and `j++` is incrementation